# Javascript updating input field ( put cursor in input )

Tags: javascript, jquery

I wanna automate login task, but after I set `$(#password").value = "mypassword";` I still have to manual click input field to get it updated. Otherwise I get error incorrect password :S I tried `$("#password").click()` but it doesn't help. What event could cause it to be updated? It's probably not "onkeyup" cause I just have to put cursor in it. So maybe someone know how to put cursor in input field with javascript? Or maybe it's something else?

Comment: $(#password").val("mypassword")

Answer (score 2):

You need to use `focus()` function also to set value use [.val()](http://api.jquery.com/val/)

```
 $("#password").val("mypassword");
 $("#password").focus();
```

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/satpalsingh/FTye8/)

Answer (score 0):

You are searching for `focus` event.

Try this:

```
$("#password").focus();
```

[Fiddle here.](http://jsfiddle.net/Pe47a/)

Comment: $("#password").focus(); not worked, but document.getElementById("password").focus() worked like a charm. Thanks all for help.

Answer (score 0):

You both forgot to open the quotes for $("#password") and use the wrong method (value instead of val).  Here's a JSfiddle with it working - http://jsfiddle.net/2bpML/1/

```
$("#password").val("mypassword");
```